# R - Interpolate Integer Values on the Increasing Order

Tags: r, interpolation, intervals, na, data-processing

I have a data frame with accumulated numbers having missing values:

```
data.frame(a=1:9, b=c(14,17,NA,20,25,29,NA,NA,41))
```

I want to fill that gaps with **integers** as uniform/distributed as possible. For instance:

- If we have 3 spaces between 5 and 10, we can have (6, 8, 9);
- If we have 4 spaces between 4 and 11, we can have (5, 7, 8, 10) or (5, 7, 9, 10).

I know this function doesn't solve:

```
seq(30, 40 ,length.out = 2)
# [1] 30 40
```

So, the expected output from data frame could be:

```
a  b
1 14
2 17
3 19
4 20
5 25
6 29
7 33
8 37
9 41
```

How can I proceed for all missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account missing values on the data frame beginning/ending have special treatment, we can use `approx` with an unique coordinate:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:9, b=c(14,17,NA,20,25,29,NA,NA,41))

missing.pos <- which(is.na(df$b))

l <- approx(x=df$b, xout = missing.pos, method = "linear") 

df$b[missing.pos] <- ceiling(l$y)

df$b
# [1] 14 17 19 20 25 29 33 37 41
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `na.interpolation` from **`imputeTS`** oder `na.approx` from **`zoo`**

Example:

```
library("imputeTS")
x <- data.frame(a=1:9, b=c(14,17,NA,20,25,29,NA,NA,41))
ceiling(na.interpolation(x))
```

The ceiling is just needed, because no decimals are wanted from the question starter.